# The simple MLP NN for regression in PyTorch - very slow learning - rev2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

After some days spent with PyTorch I ended up with the neural network, that despite being quite a good predictor, is extremely slow to learn. It is a MLP with 54 input neurons, 27 hidden neurons with sigmoid activation function, and one linear output neuron. Currently, running the NN for 20 000 epochs lasts around 20 minutes. I had some experience with PyTorch MLP with the same architecture, but 'created from scratch' - without bias, which was worse in terms of predictive capabilities, but the whole training lasted for less than 30s.

The reason I created new NN is that now my model is much more flexible (changing number of neutrons, number of layers or activation functions takes seconds). Also, I tried to use as many built-in tools as possible, so there was no problem with e.g. introducing bias to the neurons.

The code is following (I skipped the imports part):

Hyperparameters:

```py
hyperparam_input_neurons = 54
hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1 = 27
hyperparam_output_neurons = 1

param_learning_rate = 0.01
param_weight_decay = 1e-6
param_momentum = 0.9
param_epochs = 2000
param_test_data_fraction=0.5

loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

training data:

```py
train = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
Xf = torch.tensor(train.values,dtype=torch.float)
res=pd.read_csv('output.csv')
yf=torch.tensor(res.values,dtype=torch.float)

ntrainingelems=int((len(yf)+1)*param_test_data_fraction)

Xt=Xf[:ntrainingelems]
yt=yf[:ntrainingelems]

Xv=Xf[ntrainingelems:]
yv=yf[ntrainingelems:]

traintensor = TensorDataset(Xt, yt)
validtensor = TensorDataset(Xv, yv)
trainloader = DataLoader(traintensor, batch_size=ntrainingelems, shuffle=False) 
validloader = DataLoader(validtensor, batch_size=(len(yf)-ntrainingelems), shuffle=False)
```

NN definition:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(hyperparam_input_neurons, hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1)
        self.output = nn.Linear(hyperparam_hidden_neurons_1, hyperparam_output_neurons)
  
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        return x

model = Model()
```

learning:

```py
epoch_number = []
mse_loss_t = []
mse_loss_v = []


optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=param_learning_rate, weight_decay= param_weight_decay, momentum = param_momentum, nesterov = True)

for epoch in range(1, param_epochs+1):
    train_loss, valid_loss = [], []
    epoch_number.append(int(epoch))
    
    model.train()
    for data, target in trainloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
    mse_loss_t.append(np.mean(train_loss))

    model.eval()
    for data, target in validloader:
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_function(output, target)
        valid_loss.append(loss.item())        
    mse_loss_v.append(np.mean(valid_loss))
        
    if epoch==1 or epoch%100==0:
        print ("Epoch:", epoch, "Training Loss: ", np.mean(train_loss), "Valid Loss: ", np.mean(valid_loss))
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong here? Or how to make the learning quicker (at least 30x)?

FYI the very quick-to-learn 'scratch-based' NN I mentioned earlier used different definition of the forward method, so I guessed this may be the reason (see code below)... but if I understand the documentation correctly, the NN.linear can also make quick parallel computations.

```py
def forward(self, X):
        self.z = torch.matmul(X, self.W1)
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z)
        self.z3 = torch.matmul(self.z2, self.W2)
```

Comment: What shape are your target tensors? And what shape are your output tensors? Just a guess, but I'm wondering if the targets are size `(N)`; it appears that the outputs are size `(N, 1)`. If they're different, you'll see broadcasting issues from `MSELoss`, giving an `(N, N)` loss. And your code deals with the loss in a shape-agnostic way, so the bug would run silently.

Comment: Hello @AlexanderGuyer, that was a nice guess :) Indeed there was a silent warning that appeared after I started to reshape the tensors. I am not sure though whether my attitude is correct (I am not a software engineer) - I reshaped the tensors like that: from `yt=yf[:ntrainingelems]` to `yt=torch.reshape(yf[:ntrainingelems], (-1,))` (also for yv), and from `output =model(data)` to `output = torch.reshape(model(data), (-1,))`. The training time dropped by 50%, no warnings pop up so far. Still, the training time is quite far from what I desire. Do you have any other clues? BR

Comment: Did you fix this issue in both the train and validation data? Because you're constructing losses on the validation data as well, so the bug is duplicated. A more common approach for binary classifiers and scalar regression models is to flatten the output *within* the `forward()` definition of the model (prior to returning it), so as to prevent this error from appearing anywhere.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer, I changed both training and validation data, this time a little bit differently: `traintensor = TensorDataset(torch.squeeze(Xt,1), torch.squeeze(yt,1))` `validtensor = TensorDataset(torch.squeeze(Xv,1), torch.squeeze(yv,1))` and also I flattened the output in the forward() as per your remark: `output = model(data).flatten()` `output = model(data).flatten()`. In both cases (squeeze or reshape) the training time dropped 50%, but it is still far from sufficient. BTW I had to squeeze the input tensors as well, as (maybe) the DataLoader causes the tensor size [n] to be [n,1]

Comment: And additionalll, @AlexanderGuyer, when I changed the forward definition, to have the flattening there: `x= (self.output(x)).flatten()`, nothing changed in terms of training time. Still no more warnings about size mismatch (and possible errors due to broadcasting).
Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the issue - but your comments are welcome.
After applying the torch tensor sizing (to avoid (N,N) loss), I removed the DataLoader and used direct "feeding" of the data.

First change - NN object - flattening the output - size (N) instead of (N,1):

```
    def forward(self, x):
    x = self.hidden(x)
    x = torch.sigmoid(x)
    x = (self.output(x)).flatten()
    return x
```

Second change - changing the shape of the tensors:

```
traintensor_X = torch.squeeze(Xt,1)
traintensor_y = torch.squeeze(yt,1)
validtensor_X = torch.squeeze(Xv,1)
validtensor_y = torch.squeeze(yv,1)
```

Then the last, third change - removing the old DataLoaders and removing the "for data, target in trainloader" subloop. Instead, only one "main" loop is used (one for epochs):

```
for epoch in range(1, param_epochs+1): ## run the model for x epochs
train_loss, valid_loss = [], []

epoch_number.append(int(epoch))

## training part 
model.train()

optimizer.zero_grad()
## 1. forward propagation

output = model(traintensor_X)

## 2. loss calculation
loss = loss_function(output, traintensor_y)

## 3. backward propagation
loss.backward()

## 4. weight optimization
optimizer.step()

train_loss.append(loss.item())

if epoch==param_epochs:
    print("T train size: ", traintensor_X.size())
    print("T target size: ", traintensor_y.size())
    print("T output size: ", output.size())
    print("T loss size: ", loss.size())


## loss at each epoch (training set)
mse_loss_t.append(np.mean(train_loss))
    
    
## evaluation part 
model.eval()

output = model(validtensor_X)
loss = loss_function(output, validtensor_y)
valid_loss.append(loss.item())

    
## loss at each epoch (validation set)
mse_loss_v.append(np.mean(valid_loss))

if epoch==param_epochs:
    print("V train size: ", validtensor_X.size())
    print("V target size: ", validtensor_y.size())
    print("V output size: ", output.size())
    print("V loss size: ", loss.size())
    
if epoch==1 or epoch%100==0:
    print ("Epoch:", epoch, "Training Loss: ", np.mean(train_loss), "Valid Loss: ", np.mean(valid_loss))
```

I checked the dimensions of the tensors, they seem to be OK:

```
T train size:  torch.Size([4289, 54])
T target size:  torch.Size([4289])
T output size:  torch.Size([4289])
V train size:  torch.Size([2209, 54])
V target size:  torch.Size([2209])
V output size:  torch.Size([2209])
```

If you have any feedback, I'd really appreciate. Maybe I've done some silly mistake? The RMSE values are really similar to the ones from the NN with DataLoaders.